# iAD banner - Is not showing in app store

Tags: ios, delegates, store, iad, banner

I'm using storyboard, iOS7, xcode 5.1
I'm trying to add the iAD banner. When I try it by developer, testing the xcode project in device or simulator, that works well showing the Test Advertisement!

But when my app is on the App Store, it doesn't show any banner! 
And I had already enable iAd network in the itunes connect. 
In the overview: Live: This app is receiving live ads.
What am I missing?

In my .h file:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SceneDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

In my main file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}

#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In the storyboard, the delegate is connected!

Comment: When did you upload to the store?  It takes up to three days to start showing banner ads.

Comment: Really? I upload 1.0 about 6 days ago and I forgot to enable iAD Networking. The 1.0.1 was about 1 day ago. I hope you are right! The code is ok?

Comment: The code you have is very similar to the code I myself use, although I don't do an animation.  I did read just the other day in the Apple docs that it may take several days for ads to start appearing.  When you say you uploaded 1.0.1 a day ago, has it gone through the entire review process?

Comment: In my 1.0.1 I didn't change this code. I just enable iAD networking!
But how is your code without animations?

Comment: I just hide it or unhide it.  if (!_adBannerIsVisible)
    {
        _adBannerIsVisible = YES;
        _myAdBanner.hidden = NO;
    }  This goes in bannerDidLoad  and then in didFailToReceive I put this  if (_adBannerIsVisible)
    {
        _adBannerIsVisible = NO;
        _myAdBanner.hidden = YES;
    }

Comment: Also, keep us posted as to when the ads start showing.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help Douglas! Ok, I will!

Comment: Is version 1.0.1 approved by Apple and in the iTunes Store yet?  What's the App, I'll download it.

Comment: 1.0.1 was approved! But any banner! =/
Crazy Flappy Fish

Comment: Just downloaded it. I am getting banners. Fist was for deal no deal game then another game. That's as long as you are Fabio Silva!

Comment: In brazil we dont get banners from iAD?

Comment: Just found this.. The iAd Network has recently launched in Canada, Australia, and New Zealand. Ads are now available in apps in the U.S., Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Japan, France, Germany, Italy, Spain, and the U.K App Stores. Be sure to configure your apps to serve ads in only these countries.  For ads in Brazil you might want to look at another ad service like admob.

Comment: Uhnn! I have to configure to serve ads just in those countries? How can I do that? Ok, I will use admob!

Comment: I have the same problema, I used only this line to include iAds `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` and apple don't reject my app in this moment is in the App Store, in my case I don't know if the problem is because I am in Colombia?

Answer (score 0):

iAd may not be displayed on your device if there is no ad available to display targeting your device and your type of application. Even if iAd is available, there may be no advertisers that chose to launch ads that corresponds to your app.

Of course you have to make sure that you've got **iAd Advertising Network Enabled** in iTunes Connect

You can find out all metrics of iAds serving in your app and make adjustments [here](https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/). Check there if the status in iAd Network is **Live: This app is receiving live ads.**.

Comment: I say that I enable iAD network, and also my status is: Live: This app is receiving live ads

Comment: How do I find out iAd status ? on simulator it says connected to iAd network. I think with recent change one need to accept the iAd agreement. Please correct me if I am wrong. In Comments someone says it takes three days to actually receiving ads, is that true, if yes then I am just too eager to see as my app got approved today